# Grafana tooltip display value along with other text fields from the query

Tags: postgresql, tooltip, grafana

I am using Grafana v8.3.5 + Postgres.

And using the Time Series line chart where I want to display the value the query is returning, but would like that the tooltip shows me other information.

```
select timestamp as "time", value, build, version, from size;
         timestamp          | build | version   | value 
----------------------------+-------+-----------+-------
 2022-04-24 06:50:10.933324 | 1.11  | 0.1_alpha | 265
 2022-04-24 06:50:45.15727  | 2.11  | 0.1_alpha | 280
 2022-04-24 06:50:52.535592 | 3.11  | 0.1_alpha | 273
 2022-04-24 06:52:12.885316 | 4.11  | 0.1_alpha | 224
...
```

[image: graph example]

Is it possible at all that the tooltip shows all this extra information (containing strings) besides the actual value?
I tried to add a new query formatted as table, but it doesn't show up as a new series...

Comment: I have the same issue. Investigating but initial gut feel is that this is a limitation of the time series chart. https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/time-series/